# Terraform - Enforce VPC Flow logs

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-networking

I am trying to enforce VPC FLOW LOG using the organisation policy and I added this constraint , it keeps failing in terraform . what Am I doing wrong ? knowing that I am trying to enforce the sample rating to 10% and aggregation interval to 1 min.

```
-constraint: compute.requireVpcFlowLogs
    type: boolean
    folders:
    -target: company/non-prod/raul
    rules:
    -enforce: true
      values:
        allowedValues:
          -0.1
```